# How to add users manually to Meteor.users collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am having super user which I added manually and this user can other users manually through a form I give him.

lets say if I save the input entered by the user like the code shown below:

```
Session.set('name', t.find('#name').value);
Session.set('password', t.find('#pass').value);
Session.set('email', t.find('#email').value);
```

how do I store those values in those sessions in the Meteor.users, after checking that there is no match in the email and username?

and how do I encrypt the password before storing it in my database?

Comment: Why cant you create a user my making a server side meteor call and create user by using accounts.createUser() meteor method ?

Comment: Yea but what is the mongodb code to insert the user input into users.collection?

Comment: @HafizAllyLalani and if am not mistaken, you mean that i implement a function in the server side that will insert a user into Meteor.users collection? and then collect it in the client side? Am i right? Please correct me if am not :)

Comment: posted some code below, let me know if you need any specific way to do your job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code when called from the client side as:

```
Meteor.call('createUser','someemail@gmail.com','password123',function(err,res){
  .....
})
```

creates a user in Meteor.users collection with the id given below in the method

```
Meteor.methods({
  createUser(email,password){
    check(email,String);
    check(password,String);    
    let id = Accounts.createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      profile: {} //anything you like to add to profile.
    })    
  }
})
```